# How to find a particular text in UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextfield

In my iPhone app I have a `UITextField` ans text field value is being taken into an `NSString`, I want to find if a particular character **`"`** is typed in that

How can I do that?

```
UITextField *textField;
NSString *String=textField.text;

-(IBAction)FindCharecter:(id)sender
{
    // if String Contain ",then i wish to print @"Found symbol"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 UITextField *textField;
 NSString *string=textField.text;
 if ([string rangeOfString:@"\""].location == NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"string does not \"");
  } else {
   NSLog(@"string contains \"");
 }
```

check this

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
-(IBAction)FindCharecter:(id)sender
  {

    // if String Contain ",then i wish to print @"Found symbol"
     if ([String rangeOfString:@"\""].location != NSNotFound) {

          NSLog(@"Found");
     }
     else{

          NSLog(@"Not Found");
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following delegate of `UITextField`

```
-(NSString *)ValidateSearchString:(NSString *) aString{   

    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"YourString"] invertedSet];

    if ([aString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) { 
        return @"Not Found";
    }

    return @"Found";;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSLog("particular character  %@",[self ValidateSearchString:string]);

     // string will contain the particular character typed;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That won't work and seems just wrong. Your approach to create a generic method is good thinking, but you don't even use the input string to your validateSearchString method, you use a hard-coded string ("yourString"). Also you use an inverted character set. Why? The rangeOfString method is no good for finding the range of a string. It will give the range of any character in the set that appears first in the string. Just use rangeOfString. Also, why use the delegate? It's not what the OP asks for. Lastly, start the name of your methods with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method for this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([string isEqualToString:@"\""])
   {
     NSLog(@"Entered \" ");
   }
}
```

Or you can use: `rangeOfString` of `NSString` class.

```
if ([textField.text rangeOfString:@"\""].location == NSNotFound)
 {
    NSLog(@"Entered \" ");
 }
```

---

## **For reference:**

> `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
>
> Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **textField**
>
> ```
> The text field containing the text.
> ```
>
> **range**
>
> ```
> The range of characters to be replaced
> ```
>
> **string**
>
> ```
> The replacement string.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the specified text range should be replaced; otherwise, NO to
>   keep the old text. Discussion
>
> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new
>   character in the text field or deletes an existing character.
>   Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

[UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

> **rangeOfString**:
>
> Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string
>   within the receiver.
>   `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **aString**
>
> ```
> The string to search for. This value must not be nil.
>
> Important: Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aString is nil.
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of
>   the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is
>   not found or is empty (@"").
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Invokes `rangeOfString:options:` with no options.
>
> This method detects all invalid ranges (including those with negative
>   lengths). For applications linked against OS X v10.6 and later, this
>   error causes an exception; for applications linked against earlier
>   releases, this error causes a warning, which is displayed just once
>   per application execution. Availability
>
> Declared In NSString.h
>   Declared In UITextField.h

[NSString Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm and implement `UITextFieldDelegate` [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

1) If you want to check for a pattern on the go (when user typing itself), you need to implement

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
     replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

2) If you want to check when user completed typing, you may want to implement

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Now to do the actual comparison process

```
if([textFieldString rangeOfString:@"YOUR_COMPARISON_STRING"].location == NSNotFound){
     //your pattern is not typed yet
}else{
    //There it is..
}
```